# What are the dents for?

Tags: soldering, pad

I bought a few bc417 serial Bluetooth modules which have pins that look like this:

[image: pad specification]

Is there a standard name for this kind of pin?  I believe I can treat them like any other SMD pin, but I'm curious what the dents are for.  Are they intended for a header pin to go there somehow?  Just keeping your iron from slipping?  Something else?  What's the recommend way to attach these to a board?

Comment: Related question, which features castellations heavily: [Soldering PCBs directly together](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/35625/7036)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are **castellations**. They provide a larger surface area for the solder to wet when the module is surface-mount soldered to another board. They can be used to hold a pin in order to convert the module into a through-hole device, but such a practice is rarely done.

Comment: ...unless you are a hobbyst that uses breadboards :P +1

Comment: Only if the module has 2.54mm centers on opposite sides.