# ( How-To ) Ultra Low-Profile PCB Stacking

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Recently I found myself needing to stack two small circuit boards on top of each other for a modulation project. The problem is that the areas I want to connect together on the two boards have no components or traces on them, and traditional pin-style stack ups (even machine headers) leave an unwanted gap between boards.

How can I stack the boards flush with on another and have a minimal gap between them?

I have seen [This Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35625) which shows an approach to stack boards **permanently** flush together, but I need a solution that is *removable*.

Comment: No pads or solder mask either?  Do you want it removeable?  What is the wavelength?

Comment: @sunny No, nothing but flat PCB space (minus the connector of course).

Comment: WHat about the other questions.?  You need to design both mechanical and electrical interface for stickness without damage to contacts. Didn't U answer your own question?

Comment: @sunny Yes I was trying to share my discovery with the community. I also found that Escutcheon pins are a great replacement for pin headers if you don't want any protrusions.

Comment: So is this microwave? or did you consider press fit flush Swiss pin sockets used in "some" IC sockets. WOW they are gold plated Roofing nails

Comment: @sunny No, both boards feature only passives and operate at (relatively) low frequency.

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Comment: I believe castellated pads solved this problem long time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a new Sycamore contact. They allow you to plug boards together with minimal spacing in between. This is especially useful when making add-ons for a basic board which can be replaced and upgraded.

I would advise you to put a via through the edge of the contact pads (if possible) to prevent the connector ripping off the board in high-stress applications. You will be surprised how long they last!

[image: Sycamore]

There are several variations for different pin sizes and top/bottom entry:

[image: Part #s]

Here is a video: [Sycamore Contact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVDli_7XzOY)

This will require compatible male pins on your second board. For my application, female pin headers with long male legs will work, but there may come a time when you wish to attach boards without any noticeable protrusions on either board. SMD male pins that I have found so far are not adequate because they leave a gap between boards. Feel free to comment useful part #s below.

**Edit:**
I found that Escutcheon pins are a great alternative to pin headers for a protrusion-free connection to the Sycamore contact:

[image: Gold Plated Pins]

The pins are gold-plated for a longer contact life. Add a thin strip of spongy adhesive between the boards and you're good to go!

[image: Spongy Adhesive]

Comment: This reads a lot like an advertisement for this product. Are you affiliated with the company?

Comment: @ asdfex No, I have no affiliation, but I have used their sycamore contacts before and had a great experience.